# How can I find if the index number for a specific item in an array also exists as an integer in the same array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing, integer

I'm trying to find the index value of the word "odd", then return true if that index value also exists an integer within the same array.

E.g.

`array = ["even",9,"even",88,"even",777,"even",10,"odd",8,"even"]`

The index of "odd" here is [8].

When I store the index value as a variable named `odd`, then use `.include?` to see if it is in the array above, my function returns false.

Since the number 8 exists in `array` and the value of `odd` is also 8, why does my function return false?

```
def does_the_index_of_odd_exist(x)
  odd = x.each_index.select { |i| x[i] == "odd" }
  x.include?(odd)
end
```

Any help explaining this is greatly appreciated. I've just started learning!

Comment: _"The index of "odd" here is [8]"_ – note that `[8]` is an _array_ of indices, not a single index. That's because `select` returns all elements matching the condition. Either check each element for inclusion or use `find` instead of `select` if you're only interested in the first one.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the point, you should be able to use just:

```
array.include? array.index "odd"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x.each_index.select { |i| x[i] == "odd" }
=> [8] #array
but not "odd"

so use find instead of select, it returns string element in array
```

Comment: I am not sure why this is the selected answer since a) it does not solve the problem; b) it is incorrect. `x.each_index.select { |i| x[i] == "odd" }` will return `[8]` not `["odd"]` because it is iterating indices not values.

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes it returns [8] , I only meant it returns an array but not element.

Comment: What do you mean by _"but not odd"_ and _"it returns string element in array"_?

Comment: @Stefan find returns element rather than new aray, select returns a subset which is an array

Comment: @engineersmnky `x.each_index.select { |i| x[i] == "odd" }` is supposed to return 8, not "odd". I changed my code `x.each_index.find..` as suggested and it fixed my code. That's why I accepted the answer.